# Android POST java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://

Tags: android, http, post, filenotfoundexception

Hi i am trying to send bytes[] via POST in andriod byt i a get java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://xxx.xxx.xx...  ,  i got the exception when the code reach inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

any ideas ?

```
        byte[] array = new byte[]{1,1,2,3,4,4};

        String connectionString = "http://" + url + ":" + port + "/" + uploadApp;

        URL urle = new URL(connectionString);

        URLConnection httppost = urle.openConnection();
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) httppost;
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Tranz-Version-t1.914");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept_Language", "en-US");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

        outputStream.write(array);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); // here i got the eception
```

Comment: Your post doesn't have the relevant part of the code from where the exception is being thrown. Please post some logs as well.